# Archive folder not appearing in IMAP account on Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have a standard IMAP account configured in Mail.app (on Mountain Lion).

That account contains a folder called Archive, which does not appear on the list of folders on the left.

However, it does appear when I hit command+i, in the "Quota Limits" tab.

Is there anything I can do to make this folder appear?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I pressed the "archive" button (command+option+a) on a message, it moved the message to that folder and then the folder appeared on the left.